# Am I marshalling this C function correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

In C#, I am trying to PInvoke the following C method:

```
// C code:
BOOL VstSetLineDetail(
   tVstHdl pDataHdl, // type is void*
   long pLineItemNo, 
   tVstTransType pTransType, // enum type
   tVstTransSubType pTransSubType, // enum type
   tVstTransCd pTransCd, // enum type
   char *pTransDate, 
   tVstTaxedGeo *pTaxedGeoFlag, // enum type
   double *pExtdAmt, 
   double *pTotalTax, 
   double *pCombRate, 
   char *pUserArea, 
   tVstTaxingJuris *pTaxingJuris, // enum type
   char *pCustExmtCertifNum, 
   char *pDivCd, 
   char *pStoreCd, 
   char *pGLAcct)
```

I am marshalling it in C# the following way:

```
// C# code:
[DllImport(@"VertexNative\Vst.dll")]
public static extern bool VstSetLineDetail(
   [In]IntPtr dataHandle, 
   [In]long lineItemNumber, 
   [In]VstTransactionType transactionType, // an enum I defined in C#
   [In]VstTransactionSubtype transactionSubtype, // C# enum
   [In]VstTransactionCode transactionCode, // C# enum
   [In]string transactionDate, 
   [In]ref VstTaxedGeo taxedGeo, // C# enum
   [In]ref double totalAmount, 
   [In]ref double totalTax, 
   [In]ref double combinedTaxRate, 
   [In]string userArea, 
   [In]ref VstTaxingJurisdiction jurisdiction, // C# enum
   [In]string exceptionCertificate, 
   [In]string divisionCode, 
   [In]string storeCode, 
   [In]string generalLedgerAccount);
```

Calling it always produces a System.AccessViolationException. I've tried many combinations of values when calling the function, but get no better results. Can anyone tell me if it looks like I am marshalling the data types correctly?

It would be great if I had access to the C source code so I could debug, but it's a third-party set of DLLs. I can only see the header files.

The enums in C are:

```
typedef enum
{
    eVstTransTypeIgnore = 99,   /* Means ignore this parameter */
    eVstTransTypeSale = 0,
    eVstTransTypePurchase,
    eVstTransTypeService,
    eVstTransTypeRentalLease,
    eVstTransTypeNumElems,
    eVstTransTypeFirstElem = eVstTransTypeSale
} tVstTransType;

typedef enum
{
    eVstTransSubTypeIgnore = 99,    /* Means ignore this parameter */
    eVstTransSubTypeNone = 0,
    eVstTransSubTypeProperty,
    eVstTransSubTypeFreight,
    eVstTransSubTypeService,
    eVstTransSubTypeRentalLease,
    eVstTransSubTypeExpense,
    eVstTransSubTypeMisc,
    eVstTransSubTypeNumElems,
    eVstTransSubTypeFirstElem = eVstTransSubTypeNone
} tVstTransSubType;

typedef enum
{
    eVstTransCdIgnore = 99, /* Means ignore this parameter */
    eVstTransCdNormal = 0,
    eVstTransCdAdjustment,
    eVstTransCdTaxOnlyDebit,
    eVstTransCdTaxOnlyCredit,
    eVstTransCdDistributeRate,
    eVstTransCdDistributeTax,
    eVstTransCdNumElems,
    eVstTransCdFirstElem = eVstTransCdNormal
} tVstTransCd;

typedef enum
{
    eVstTaxedGeoNone = 0,
    eVstTaxedGeoDetermine,
    eVstTaxedGeoShipTo,
    eVstTaxedGeoShipFrom,
    eVstTaxedGeoOrderAccept,
    eVstTaxedGeoNumElems,
    eVstTaxedGeoFirstElem = eVstTaxedGeoNone
} tVstTaxedGeo;

typedef enum {  
    eVstTaxingJurisPrimary,
    eVstTaxingJurisAddtl,
    eVstTaxingJurisNumElems,
    eVstTaxingJurisFirstElem = eVstTaxingJurisPrimary
} tVstTaxingJuris;
```

And I've defined them in C# as:

```
public enum VstTransactionType
{
      Sale,
      Purchase,
      Service,
      RentalLease,
      Ignore = 99
}

public enum VstTransactionSubtype
{
     None,
     Property,
     Freight,
     Service,
     RentalLease,
     Expense,
     Misc,
     Ignore = 99
}

public enum VstTransactionCode
{
     Normal,
     Adjustment,
     TaxOnlyDebit,
     TaxOnlyCredit,
     DistributeRate,
     DistributeTax,
     Ignore = 99
}

public enum VstTaxedGeo
{
     None,
     Determine,
     ShipTo,
     ShipFrom,
     OrderAccept
}

public enum VstTaxingJurisdiction
{
      Primary,
      Additional
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to post the corresponding C and C# structs too.  Since they are passed by value, it's likely that the sizes of the two structs are not exactly the same, and this is resulting in corruption of that argument as well as all following arguments.

Comment: Does your C function expect Unicode or Ansi strings? Also you don't really need to say `[In]` here.

Comment: I've added the definitions for the enums in C and C#. Anton, where do I look to see if it's expecting Unicode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not right, because `long` in C isn't 8 bytes like it is in C# (it's often 4 bytes). Also, a `char*` isn't necessarily a `string`, because `string`s are meant to be immutable, and you can only safely marshal them to `const char*`, since only that can guarantee that the C code won't modify them. If you need to make them mutable, use `StringBuilder` instead of `string`, and use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]` or the like.

Comment: So instead of long I should pass int?

Comment: Yes, assuming your C compiler uses 32 bits for `long` (which is often the case).
Also, `char*` is usually ANSI, so you might want to use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] on those parameters.

Comment: A little side note, but I think it's worth mentioning that whether or not you get an error might actually be different on a 64-bit system, because of how parameters are passed... if the parameters are passed in registers, for example (which I think happens for the first few arguments in a 64-bit environment), you might not get any errors in that architecture, but you might in a different one. Be careful about that.

Comment: Using an int as the parameter type has solved it! Thanks Lambert!